# What is the command for promoting a peek preview to document?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

When I'm in peek preview, I sometimes wish to promote it to document. It's done by mousing on the icon as shown below.

[image]

On occasion (most of the occasion, in fact), my mouse is tired and wants me to use my keyboard for such promotion to document. According to [the wisdom on the net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320181.aspx), it's achieved by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>.

In my VS, there's nothing assigned to the key combination, so I'm guessing someone snack in and changed that without my permission. However, to restore it, I need to know what the command in *Tools | Options  | Environment |Keyboard* is called.

I can't find anything appropriate there (I've tried different variations of the MS's description of the command: "*Promote the Peek Definition window to a regular document tab*").

So, what is it called? If it differs between versions, I'd like to know the name for each, where the peeking is avaialble (started in VS13, if I'm not mistaken).

*Given the meaningful effort I've put into composing the image, every and each can clearly see that it's a crucial and important matter, given the circumstances.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 the command name is `Window.KeepTabOpen`.

Comment: Very poorly maintained correlation between command name and tool tip description, in such case. Hardly your fault, though. I'll accept it as soon as I'll have a chance to test it.

Comment: I can't get this to work in VS 2015; assigning a shortcut to Window.KeepTabOpen doesn't promote the peek editor.

Comment: @TomGilder Me too. Looks like a bug in VS 2015, as I can't find another command to promote the peek editor.

Comment: @TomGilder I was about to start upgrading to VS15 tihs weekend. Great that you gave me heads-up. I hate when I upgrade and get **less** stuff than I had before. Appreciate the comment. You might post it as a reply too.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Any idea on when that can be resolved? Is it reported? If so, how can we track the status? If not, how do we report it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'm not aware how MS plans to improve it (still doesn't work in VS 2015 CTP1). Technically, this button probably can be clicked programmatically and integrated as a command with something like Visual Commander.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Any news about the issue? I'm also looking for a keyboard shoкесге for this action.

Comment: @deko Sadly, nope. Apparently, the issue wasn't regarded as important enough to fix. Weird, in my opinion, so I'll guess that the team hasn't got up the eyes on it, simply. I haven't tested in the Update 3 of VS 2015 nor in VS15 (I know, I know, the naming sucks) but I have limited hopes.

Comment: This works in VS 2017 for anyone who comes across this answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but on reverse. I hate the Peek Definition and didn't know how to get rid of it. Well, I found it. In Visual Studio 2017 you need to go to **Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> General -> Control click options**. There you need to check/uncheck the **Control click shows definitions in Peek**
[image]

Hope it helps!

PS. In order to see **Productivity Power Tools** you need to get it first using NuGet

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this (for Visual Studio 2015) is the following:

With focus on the peek window to open/dock:

1. Close peek window

   - <kbd>Esc</kbd>
2. Go to definition

   - <kbd>F12</kbd>
3. Pin tab

   - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>

If there are multiple/nested peeks, then replace step 1 with:

1. Previous peek window

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>