# How can I run a foreach loop in the immediate window of visual studio?

Tags: c#, foreach, visual-studio-2017, immediate-window

I am trying to write values to a file using the `Immediate Window` in Visual Studio 2017.

I've got a variable called `_myItems` which is of type `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<int>>>`.

I did hit a `breakpoint` where this variable is in scope. I can run

```
?_myItems
```

in the window, and I'll get a list like:

```
Count = 9
    [0]: {[536], System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]]}
    [1]... omitted for clearance
    ...    omitted for clearance
    ...    omitted for clearance
    [8]... omitted for clearance
```

To make sure that I can write a file in the immediate window, I ran:

```
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "testing purposes");
```

Which did write the file, therefore I am sure I can write to a file from there.

I then tried the following:

```
?(foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<int, List<int>>> pair in _myItems) { foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> valuePair in pair.Value) { foreach (int numberToWrite in valuePair.Value) { File.AppendAllText("test.txt",numberToWrite.ToString()); } }})
```

But I am getting the following error:

> error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'foreach'

By searching around I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278201/how-to-execute-linq-and-or-foreach-in-immediate-window-in-vs-2013) but the accepted answer only state that you can do it.

How can I run this `foreach` loop in the Immediate Window to write the values to the file.

Note that I am aware that I should've done that inside my code, but I didn't think that I'll need the values later on. I was just checking the average. When I finished using the application I wrote, I decided to use those values. Given the time of preparing the values takes hours and hours, there's no possibility of just stopping the execution and re-write what I need in my code and go through the whole process again.

I am also aware that I can run

```
?_myItems[536][0]
```

Then copying the values manually in the file. This process will also take a long time giving there's a lot of lists, and I would like to avoid it.

**Is there any possibility to make this work in the immediate window?**

**Update**:

I did as suggested in the answers:

```
_myItems.Select(x => x.Value)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(pair => pair
                                     .ToList()
                                     .ForEach(valuePair => valuePair
                                                           .Value
                                                           .ForEach(numberToWrite => File.AppendAllText("test.txt", numberToWrite.ToString()))))
```

I got the following error:

> Evaluation of method System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]].ForEach() calls into native method Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetFullPathName(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.

I even tried to just `Debug.Print` my values, for example like:

```
_myItems.ToList().ForEach(pair => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(pair.Key));
```

And I ended up getting the same error above. This time with the error of calling the native method:

> System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsLogging()

I searched for this error and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35983978/6783663) it's suggested to tick the *Use Managed Compatibility Mode* from debugging options. However, this option is grayed out in my case since I am already in a debugging session I assume.

Comment: Note, you don't need to use the ? prefix in the Immediate window.

Answer (score 4):

As [`.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2) does not exist on the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type it only exists on the `List<T>` class.

Alternatively you can select the values of the dictionary, convert it into a list and walk through every value and write it into the file.

Adding to [Helio Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903849/helio-santos) I would like to add:

```
_myItems.Select(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(pair => pair.ForEach(intList => intList.ForEach(numberToWrite => File.AppendAllText("test.txt", numberToWrite.ToString()))));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my question with an error that I got.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your foreach chain to a linq expression:

```
_myItems.Select(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(pair => pair.ForEach(intList => intList.ForEach(numberToWrite => File.AppendAllText("test.txt", numberToWrite.ToString()))));
```